# Algolia dynamic facets options

Tags: javascript, algolia, instantsearch.js

the problem is the following. 
We use algolia instantsearch. 
Each product has seller. The current user is subscribed to some sellers. The user should have the possibility to filter the products by  subscribed sellers and those that have not. 
For this I have tried to use widget toggle.  where I set list of subsribed sellers for current user separated by commas as on and off options

```
values: {
  on: '37,41,67',
  off: '45,56',
},
```

But it works only if I specify only one seller. And fulfills the default option is off. 
I have tried to use numericRefinementList widget

```
options: [
  { label: 'On', value: '37,41,67' },
  { label: 'Off', value: '45,56' },
],
```

But it not working also
Can someone suggest a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a behaviour covered by the default widgets. However you can make custom widget that would switch on the list of filters. Let me give you an example:

```
const sellerList = [];
// this uses jQuery
const toggleButton = $('div.toggleSellers');
const search = instantsearch(/* parameters and credentials */);
search.addWidget({
  getConfiguration: function() {
    return {disjunctiveFacets: ['seller']};
  },
  init: function(options) {
    const helper = options.helper;  
    // Here you have to bind the event that will toggle seller
    // For example using the `toggleButton` and a click event
    toggleButton.on('click', function() {
      sellerList.forEach(function(seller) {
        helper.toggleRefinement('seller', seller);
      });
    });
  },
});
```

`"seller"` is the name of the attribute in your records that contain the seller. It should be configured as a facet in your Algolia dashboard.

`sellerList` is a list of seller identifiers that are used in the `"seller"` attribute in your index.

This custom widget is using the [jsHelper](https://community.algolia.com/algoliasearch-helper-js/reference.html) which let you specify the parmaeters of the search. Also you can find more infos in the doc regarding [the custom widgets](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/documentation/#custom-widgets).